# What did Montague mean?

Tags: the-tudors

In *The Tudors*, when Edward (late queen Jane's brother) came to the tower for Lord Montague to take him *to a better place*, after his guilt had been established, Montague said,

> You know, my lord.. this is the truth: The king never made a man but he destroyed him again. So take good care, my lord.

What did he mean?

Answer (score 5):

He's saying that the king had a habit of elevating men to higher positions, but then [abandoning them](https://www.thirteen.org/wnet/sixwives/portrait/little.html) when they displeased him (and often even had them executed).

> In Henry's case, old friends fell by the wayside. Old allies were executed. Thomas Cromwell, broker for Henry's failed marriage to Anne of Cleves and architect of the English Reformation, was one of the more sensational victims. After botching Rome's support for Henry's first divorce, 20-year-plus retainer Cardinal Thomas Wolsey only escaped execution through a natural death.

---

You're probably tripping over the "never... but" structure of the sentence. Perhaps you'll grasp its meaning in the sentence "It never rains but it pours", which can be "translated" as "Whenever it rains, it pours", i.e. the first part cannot exist without the second part.

See also https://english.stackexchange.com/a/280537/91509 .

Answer (score 1):

[Google's dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+but) provides an archaic definition for "but":

> without it being the case that

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/but) provides a similar definition (though without the archaic note):

> without the circumstance that

We can therefore modify the quote slightly, to be this:

> The king never made a man without it being the case that he destroyed him again.

In other words, the king has never made a man - given him power, wealth, respect, etc. - without also destroying him later on.